# Unable to convert string read from bluetooth to int

Tags: serial, servo, softwareserial, hc-05, hc-06

I am using a HC-06 and i want to read a number ending with f as a delimiter, the first three numbers as my servo position, however converting the string into int is giving an endless series of 0s. I added the Serial.print(servopos) to see that its a never ending series of 0s, and nothing seems to fix this problem. What am I doing wrong? (I tried using long for servopos instead of int, it didn't fix the issue)

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Servo.h> 

Servo myservo; // servo name

int bluetoothTx = 10; 
int bluetoothRx = 11;
int fwd = 12; 
int bwd = 13;

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(bluetoothTx, bluetoothRx);
String content = "";
char character;

void setup()
{
  myservo.attach(9); // attach servo signal wire to pin 9
  //Setup usb serial connection to computer
  Serial.begin(9600);

  //Setup Bluetooth serial connection to android
  bluetooth.begin(9600);

  pinMode(fwd, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(bwd, OUTPUT);

}

void loop()
  { 
  if(bluetooth.available()> 0 ) // receive number from bluetooth

    character = bluetooth.read();

    if (character!='f'){
        content += (char) character;
        delay(10);
      }

    else{
      int servopos = content.substring(0,3).toInt(); 
      Serial.print(servopos);
     // myservo.write(servopos); 

      String directMvt = content.substring(3);
      if (directMvt == "00"){
            digitalWrite(fwd, LOW);
            digitalWrite(bwd, LOW);
      }
      else if (directMvt == "10"){
            digitalWrite(fwd, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(bwd, LOW);
      }
      else if (directMvt == "01"){
            digitalWrite(fwd, LOW);
            digitalWrite(bwd, HIGH);
      }
      else if (directMvt == "11"){
            digitalWrite(fwd, LOW);
            digitalWrite(bwd, LOW);
      }
      content = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried examining the contents of `directMvt` yet?

Comment: Don't post code as picture. Use copy paste

Comment: Instead of printing the converted number, try printing the substring, that you try to convert in the line above. Most likely the substring doesn't contain only numbers

Comment: Don't put delays in serial receiving code!

Comment: I printed the directMvt and the substring, they give the right answer, the problem seems to be in the toInt() function @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: I printed the content of the substring before converting, it contains only the number i entered, for example if I enter 18000f, the first substring contains 180 and the second 00, I posted the code instead of the pic @chrisl

Comment: I had to put delays because I had the issue that the same characters arrives many times, because the sender sends slower than the loop, I had things like 1118888000000 for 18000f @ChrisStratton

Comment: That can only happen with a logic bug.  Fix the logic bug.  **Do not use a delay**, it a proof of misunderstanding.

Comment: the thing I believe the loop in the arduino code is faster than rate at which the cellphone sends the data thats why it happens and stops with delay, but I'll try to remove it again and see if I had a logical problem with my previous code @ChrisStratton

Comment: Of course the loop is faster; but that's not a problem with a proper program.

Comment: Do you think the android code is causing the issue with the delay ? The arduino code doesnt have any bug no? @ChrisStratton

Comment: Do you have any idea about the toInt() issue ? @ChrisStratton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found your problem: You have a missing pair of `{ }`, that should enclose the `if(bluetooth.available()>0)` statement. Without the parenthesis it only encloses the following statement, which is the serial reading.

Now follow the logic: Before you are sending something over serial, the global variable `character` should be zero. So then, since the NULL character is not equal to `f`, the NULL characters are added to the string. Then you send a string like `18000f` via bluetooth serial. The code is adding the characters to the string variable, until it find the `f` character. Now it goes directly in the `else`-statement, printing the value of `servopos` and then resetting the string variable. On the next loop iteration, there isn't something available at the SoftwareSerial, so it goes to the `if(character !='f')` statement. The `character` variable is global and it is still filled with the `f` value, that it got in the last loop iteration. So the `else` statement is executed forever very fast. But since you reseted the content of the string variable in the last iteration, there is nothing to convert to integer here. So this gives you a forever lasting series of zeros.

Enclosing the code in the first `if` statement solves your problem, since then, it only does something, when data is available at the serial interface. Also you should consider using a local variable for `character`, since you only need it there and your problem would have been obvious (through a compiler error), if you used a local variable here. Using global variables, when there is no need to, can make things more complex and error-prone.